# Drawing monochromatic colors of a hue

Tags: matlab, plot, colors, matlab-figure, hsv

Based on wiki [page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monochromatic_color), monochromatic colors are all the colors (tones, tints and shades) of a single hue. An example of monochromatic colors for 'red' is also shown. I was wondering if there is any ways to generate this in MATLAB for any hue like red, green, blue?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @Guto for the idea. Here is my MATLAB code to draw the monochromatic colors of red.

Both previous answers plot `tints` of red. Monochromatic refers to the full spectrum of one hue. In other words, monochromatic colors are all the colors (tones, tints and shades) of a single hue.

```
h = zeros(10,1); % red
steps = 20;

% tints (reducing saturation while value is constant in HSV)
s = linspace(1,0.1,10); % stop S at 0.1
v = ones(10,1);
hsv_colormap_tints = [h s' v];

% shades (reducing value while saturation is constant in HSV)
s = ones(10,1);
v = linspace(1,0.1,10); % stop V at 0.1
hsv_colormap_shades = [h s v'];

% remove the first row
hsv_colormap_tints = hsv_colormap_tints(2:end,:);
% and then flip
hsv_colormap_tints = flipud(hsv_colormap_tints);
% appending two color maps
hsv_colormap = [hsv_colormap_tints' hsv_colormap_shades']';
% convert to RGB model
rgb_colormap = hsv2rgb(hsv_colormap);

ax = figure(1);
colormap(ax, rgb_colormap);

[x,y] = meshgrid(1:steps,1:steps);
h = surface(x,y');
set(h,'edgecolor','none');
title('Monochromatic colors of red', 'FontSize', 20);
% hide both axis
set(gca,'xtick',[]);
set(gca,'ytick',[]);
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

**Yes**. However a precise answer depends how you draw the "figure".

[`colormap`](https://se.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/colormap.html) Is a function that you want in case you have a surface plot.

[`color`, `markerfacecolor`,`markeredgecolor`](https://se.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/matlab.graphics.chart.primitive.line-properties.html) are properties in case ou plot lines and markers.

[`image`](https://se.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/image.html) is the function when you work with image. It is an array with RGB values.

In all the cases, color is specified by [r g b], but for a colormap and image they are a matrix with all the values for every step or pixel, respectively. Follow an example with surface plot and a custom `colormap`.

```
[x,y]=meshgrid(1:10,1:10);
surface(x,y) %this will give a 'plane', but with the default color. 
%creating a proper colormap from white to red
r=ones(10,1); %always red
g=linspace(0,1,10); %linear increase
b=g; %copy green to blue
redmap=[r g' b'];
colormap(redmap)
```

giving this graph:
[image]

Notice that i make a RGB scale using 10 points, you can make it as fine as you want, as long you have a full red (always 1), and green and blue increase linearly and with same values all the time. `[1 1 1]` is white, `[1 0 0]` is red, `[0 1 0]` is green and `[0 0 0]` is black. Other colors you can check in one of the sections of the [`colormap` manual](https://se.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/colormap.html).

Comment: Thanks! but this is `tints` of red!

Comment: @ManiAm, True, however  the shades are just making it goes to 0 instead of 1. But I also like your approach of using HSV, as it ensure to keep in the same hue and has an easier approach to those not used to handling direct RGB values.

Answer (score 2):

You can get this effect by changing the alpha value of your color (while keeping the RGB values constant).

Here's a small demonstration using semi-transparent polygons:

```
function q48731598(drawBG)
%% Handling inputs:
if nargin < 1
  drawBG = true;
end
%% Constants:
LEVELS = 10;
%% User input:
c = uisetcolor([1 1 0], 'Select a color');
%% The rest...
alph = linspace(0.1, 1, LEVELS);

bg = checkerboard(8,30); % default background
sz = size(bg);
if ~drawBG
  bg = ones(sz); % create a white background of the same size
end

figure(); imshow(bg); hold on;

for ind1 = 1:LEVELS % create several polygons:
  patch([1, sz(1) sz(1) 1], ...
        [1+(ind1-1)*sz(2)/LEVELS*[1 1] (1+(ind1-0)*sz(2)/LEVELS-1)*[1 1]],...
        c, 'FaceAlpha', alph(ind1));
end
```

If you run it like `q48731598(false)` and choose the red color, you'll get:

[image]

When the [`checkerboard`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/checkerboard.html) background is visible:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

To build up on @Guto asnwer, in matlab you can directly use the `hsv2rgb()` function. That way, you can be sure you are only changing the saturation and value for a constant hue.
Here is an example:

```
figure
N = 10;
[x,y]=meshgrid(0:N,0:N);
surface(x,y) %this will give a 'plane', but with the default color. 
%creating a proper colormap from white to red
h = zeros(N,1) + 1;     % Constant hue = 100%
s = linspace(1,0,N)';   % Variable saturation
v = zeros(N,1) + 1;     % Constant value
rgb = hsv2rgb([h,s,v]);
colormap(rgb)
```

[image: Constant hue, variable saturation]

With a small modification, you can plot hues:

```
figure
N = 30;
[x,y]=meshgrid(0:N,0:N);
surface(x,y)
h = linspace(1,0,N)';   % Sweep hused
s = h.*0 + 1;
v = s;
colormap(hsv2rgb([h,s,v]))
```

[image: Hue sweep]